# Module not found when importing a package. It is definitely installed on the computer. I've tried many things already, and none worked

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, macos-catalina

I'm using MacOS Catalina. I'll explain everything I did. I'm desperate and it feels like I tried everything. Currently, when I type the following in the terminal, I get:

- "python --version"  --> "Python 2.7.16"
- "python3 --version" --> "Python 3.7.4"
- "brew info python"  --> "python: stable 3.7.4 (bottled), HEAD"

**Process**:

A couple weeks ago, before "upgrading" to Catalina, Anaconda, conda and pip commands were working just fine and I could install and import packages (like geopandas) normally while using Jupyter notebooks. After the update, Anaconda wouldn't launch and after a few attempts at fixing it, I decided to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda from scratch, which worked to open Anaconda and work with the Jupyter notebooks normally. Today, I tried to install geojson running the command "pip install geojson" which is what I normally did before the update. It did install the package, but both pip and pip 3 had python 2.7 as target folder for the install (and I use python 3 in the notebook). Here I tried doing everything to make it change the installation target to 3.7, but eventually I got frustrated and figured it would be better to reinstall everything. I uninstalled pip, Homebrew, Anaconda, and anything I could find relating to these two, and reinstalled Homebrew (which told me to specifically use pip3 for installs) and the Anaconda full package again.

**Problems**:

- conda command is not working: "command not found: conda" (which is weird because it comes with anaconda, but okay, not essential)
- when running "pip3 install geojson" in the terminal at first, I received the message:

  > Requirement already satisfied: geojson in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.5.0)

  so I uninstalled through "pip3 uninstall geojson", which worked. Then I reinstalled with 
  "pip3 install geojson" and got the messages:

  > WARNING: The directory '/Users/myname/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
  >
  > WARNING: The directory '/Users/myname/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
  >
  > Collecting geojson
  >   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/8d/9e28e9af95739e6d2d2f8d4bef0b3432da40b7c3588fbad4298c1be09e48/geojson-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  >   Installing collected packages: geojson
  >   Successfully installed geojson-2.5.0
- Attempting to reinstall again got me the message

  > Requirement already satisfied: geojson in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.5.0)

  which definitely means the package is installed for python 3.7. Now, when I try to run in 
  the Jupyter notebook: "import geojson", it reads the message "Module not found" all over 
  again.

How can I fix this? Will try anything at this point. By the way, the Notebook runs python 3. Also, I tried doing all of the above the same but with sudo already. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Also, this also happens with any other package I try to install now (like geopandas, which definitely worked before). While troubleshooting I also tried something really sketchy while trying to modify the target path for pip3 BEFORE doing the general uninstalls and reinstalls: **vi $(which pip3)** and modified the "#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python" on top with something I thought would work, but I figured that by reninstalling, this ungodly thing I did would not matter anymore.

Comment: Same here :( I'm not using Anaconda, but I do have upgraded to Catalina. Did you also switch your shell to zsh as Catalina recommends you whenever you start the Terminal after upgrading? I wonder if this has something to do with switching from bash to zsh.

Comment: Yep, I did switch to zsh. My bet is this has to do with the fact that Catalina comes with Python 3 already, and the pathings could have been messed up.

Comment: I don’t think it does, but Xcode 11 looks like it does. I tried a switch back to bash and it worked again. Still didn’t find a way to make it work in zsh without messing it all up though.

Comment: I went for the use of virtual environments and it seems to work fine. Fixed, I guess.